# Установить курсор на другое приложение

Tags: android, accessibility

Мне нужно из моего фонового андроид приложения установить курсор на текстовом поле другого приложения с помощью accessibility сервиса. Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы установить курсор в текстовое поле другого приложения, вы можете использовать следующий пример кода:

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo targetNode = null;
AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNode = getRootInActiveWindow();

if (rootNode != null) {
  List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> nodeList = rootNode.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("package_name:id/edit_text_id");

  if (nodeList != null && !nodeList.isEmpty()) {
    targetNode = nodeList.get(0);
  }
}

if (targetNode != null) {
  targetNode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_FOCUS);
}
```

Где `package_name` – это пакетное имя приложения, в котором находится текстовое поле, `id/edit_text_id` – это `ID` текстового поля.

Обратите внимание, что для использования `Accessibility API` ваше приложение должно иметь разрешение `android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE`. Также необходимо убедиться, что другое приложение включено в список доступных сервисов доступности в настройках устройства.